# JavaScript - Middle number from array using the reduce function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a program which would calculate the average number, by dividing the sum of all numbers with the total number of numbers. I tried to use the `.reduce()` function, but it won't give me the result I want. For example, if I take "4" and "2", the program should make a sum of those two, which is "6" and then divide it by "2" (since there are two numbers that make the sum), so in the end I would get "3". However, what I keep getting is "21", most likely because the program concatenates the "4" and "2", so that the result would be "42" and then it divides with "2". How can I change the code to get the right result?

```js
var numOfNum = 0;
var result;
var allNums = [];
var total = 0;

function add() {

  var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value;

  if (numbers > 5) {
    alert("Maximum character limit reached.");
  } else {
    allNums.push(numbers);
    numOfNum++;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = allNums + "<br>" + numOfNum;
  }

  total = allNums.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

}

function calculate() {
  result = total / numOfNum

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Racunanje proseka</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="racunanjeProseka.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="numbers"> <br>
  <button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <button id="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numbers needs to be a Number:

```
var numbers = +document.getElementById("numbers").value;
```

This additional + is called the *unary plus operator* wich converts strings into numbers.

Answer (score 2):

you can parse the value before adding

```
total = allNums.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  }, 0);
```